# How to access JavaFx node elements values in methods of FXML Controller class?

Tags: javafx

It seems values of nodes (textfields, checkboxes, etc...) can only be accessed via an event listener on them. Why am I saying that ?
- First I'm new to JavaFx
- Second : below is the scenario I'm using

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private JFXCheckBox myCheckBox;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton myButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         myCheckBox.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e)->{
                if(myCheckBox.isSelected()){
                System.out.Println("Printed from event handler");
         });

         myButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e) -> {
                myMethod();        
         });
    }

    public void myMethod(){
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
          for(Node node : root.getChildrenUnmodifiable()){
              if(node.getId().equals("myCheckBox"){
                 JFXCheckBox myChk = (JFXCheckBox) node;
                 if(myChk.isSelected()){
                    System.out.Println("Printed from my inner method");
                 }
                 System.out.Println(myChk.isSelected());
              }
          }
    }

}
```

What happend is when I check the box, the event handler does how supposed. It prints `Printed from event handler`. But right afetr that, when clicking `myButton`, the `myMethod` always prints `false`.

When I use a class variable indicating if the checkbox is selected and read it in `myMethod`, it says the check box has been checked ...

What is going on ?

The same thing happens with textfields ...

Comment: You're loading the FXML file again... The new checkbox you get when you load the file again hasn't been checked. It's not really clear what you're asking - you already have a reference to the check box anyway. Why not just do `System.out.println(myCheckBox.isSelected())` in `myMethod()`?

Comment: @James_D Ha Ha.. Eureka !!! Nice one James_D. Actually I'm doing that because I want to write an input valudation method. That's why I'm loading the FXML an iterating its nodes. How can I get the original FXML (i.e the original stage) whenever I want without reloading it ?   Or should I work in the `Application` class for such manipulation.... (as a beginner I still trying to figure out when to work in which classes ...)

Comment: @James_D  Then again my question sustains.... How can I access those element in my Controller methods without reloading the FXML ?  Since that FXML is instantiate in the `Application` class

Comment: Again, you already have references to those nodes, via injection. E.g. in `myMethod()` you can just refer to `myCheckBox`, and you will get its correct selected state. It's not really clear what the issue is.

Comment: @James_D Okay I understand now. But what if I'd lik to use `for` loop to iterate thought the FXML node... Further in my code I used  stuff like `if(node.getClass().toString().equals("class com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField"))` since I want to avoid writing a line for each `@FXML` variable... Is it possible ?

Comment: @Bloomberg58 just give your root an fx:id and inject it the same as you did with myCheckbox.

Comment: Well, don't use code like that (at worst do `if (node instanceof JFXTextField)`). But why not just inject the root node, and then iterate through its children?

Comment: @James_D Awesome. It worked. Special thanks for the `instanceof`.... Really helped me James_D. Thank you mate.... Write an answer do I accept it.It may help someone in the future....

Comment: @MMAdams  Thank you mate. Please vote me up. JavaFx is new to some people